# How can I set label location in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking for some help to set a location for my labels. I would like to have them in the top left corner of the chart if possible.

Otherwise worst case scenario would be to have have a future offset. I'm lost in where to start with this, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

```
//@version=4
study("Order Flow Share Size Calculator", overlay=true)



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Inputs
risk = input(100.00, "Risk Amount (USD)", type=input.float)
Show_Label_Long = input(true, title="Long Position")
Show_Label_Short = input(true, title="Short Position")

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Variables and Calculations Long
EntryL = high + 0.01
StopL = low - 0.01
StoplossL = EntryL - StopL
SharesL = round(risk/StoplossL)

// Long Label
LongLabel = "Shares = " + tostring(SharesL) + "\n" + "\nEntry = $" + tostring(round(EntryL * 100)/100) + "\n" + "\nStop = $" +tostring(round(StopL * 100)/100)


// Variables and Calacutations Short
EntryS = low - 0.01
StopS = high + 0.01
StoplossS = StopS - EntryS
SharesS = round(risk/StoplossS)

// Short Lables
ShortLabel = "Shares = " + tostring(SharesS) +"\n" + "\nEntry = $" + tostring(round(EntryS * 100)/100) + "\n" + "\nStop = $" +tostring(round(StopS *100)/100)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Create Label Long
if Show_Label_Long

LL = label.new (x=bar_index, y=na, text=LongLabel, xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.green, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.green, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)

label.delete(LL[1])



// Create Label Short
if Show_Label_Short
SL = label.new (x=bar_index, y=na, text=ShortLabel, xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.red, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)

label.delete(SL[1])

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, now labels in pine hasn't absolute position. But you can try something like this to offset your label in future:

```
//@version=4
study("Label in future", overlay=true)

count = input(1)

// we use minimal time of bars as an offset in future 
var float minBarTime = 999999999999
var label l = label.new(bar_index, close, "Text", xloc=xloc.bar_time)
currentTime = time(timeframe.period)
timeOfCurrentBar = change(currentTime, 1)
minBarTime := not na(minBarTime) ? min(timeOfCurrentBar, minBarTime) : timeOfCurrentBar
// add to current time calculated time of bar
label.set_x(l, int(currentTime+(count*minBarTime)))
label.set_y(l, hl2)
```